# Why are my specified ranges being ignored while using Table?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, output

I am trying to plot a complex function with ListPointPlot3D, which requires the use of a table. My code is as follows:
`SampleLevel = 0.1;`

`data := Table[(1 - m)*(-((.5*((1 - m)*l)^(-.5)*(-.25)*((1 - m) l)^(-1.5)*(-l))/(1 - t))/(((.5*((1 - m) l)^(-.5)*(-.25)*((1 - m) l)^(-1.5)*(1 - m))/(1 - t)) - 1)) - l, {m, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel}, {l, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel}, {t, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel}]`

`ListPointPlot3D[data, AxesLabel -> {"m", "l", "t"}]`

With the output of this 3D dot plot:
[image: The image of the resulting code being executed]

Strangely, the resulting plot has some very odd results on the axes. I understand that m and l go up to 10, as that is the number of samples to get to 1 (0.1 * 10 = 1), though the t axis remains a mystery. Why are the values going negative when t is specified to go between 0.01 and 0.99?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean `ListPointPlot3D[data], AxesLabel -> {"m", "l", "t"}]`? If so the result does not match the image in the question.

Comment: Yes I did. I've edited the post to reflect that

Comment: The value of the expression is negative for `t` in the range `{t, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel}`. Do you get the same plot as the image? I do not.

Comment: I apologize. For some reason the range for m was deleted which I have since added back. Your output should match now

Comment: What is it that you want to plot?  You've generated a 10x10x10 array of values of a function dependent on `m`, `l`, and `t` but as @lericr mentions in an answer, that's not the expected format for `ListPointPlot3D`.  Do you want to generate 1,000 sets of `{m, l, t, functionvalue}`?  But that's a 4-dimensional dataset.  So describing what you want in words would be helpful.

Comment: I'm attempting to take the datapoints of 3 different equations for any value of m, l, and t, that satisfies said equation. I found that using a table lets my output datapoints and I was just planning on seeing if they fit the equation values myself in something like Excel. Here, I am just trying to visualize and understand the datapoints that Table is generating @JimB

Comment: Well, as @JimB says, you're trying to analyze 4D data. Unless your brain has special 4D visualization capability, you're not going to be able to analyze the entire data set visually. What you could do is analyze slices.

Comment: Each data point has the form {m, l, t, V), where V = f(m,l,t) and f is the function you're using in your Table. So, fix one input argument, say t=0.01. You can do this with your current Table structure, but you'll still get 4D data, so you'll need to strip out the 3rd element. Or you can apply t=0.01 to your formula first and then produce a reduced Table. Either way you'll end up with 3D data, and you can plot points {m, l, f(m,l,0.01)}. You can do this multiple times fixing one of the 3 variables to get interesting slices to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation on ListPointPlot3D and the look at your data's shape, you'll see that you're matching the third variant of ListPointPlot3D. The different colors you're getting in your plot are the colors that it's assigning to the different subsets of your data. Each subset of your data is  matching the second variant of ListPointPlot3D.

Since your data is not in the form for the first variant, it's not interpreting your data as a list of points. Instead it's interpreting it a list of height values arrayed over a 2D grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SampleLevel = 0.1;

data = Table[(1 - 
       m)*(-((.5*((1 - m)*l)^(-.5)*(-.25)*((1 - m) l)^(-1.5)*(-l))/(1 - 
            t))/(((.5*((1 - m) l)^(-.5)*(-.25)*((1 - m) l)^(-1.5)*(1 - 
               m))/(1 - t)) - 1)) - l,
   {m, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel},
   {l, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel},
   {t, 0.01, 0.99, SampleLevel}];
```

The  "z" axis are the function values from the `Table` argument.

```
ListPointPlot3D[data,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold, Blue] & /@
    {"t", "l", "f"}),
 DataRange -> {{0.01, 0.91}, {0.01, 0.91}},
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[
   Range[0.01, 0.91, SampleLevel],
   LegendLabel -> Style["m", 14, Bold, Blue],
   LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]